# How make one section 100vh height becomes pixels after the page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Site -> http://bit.ly/1ocSOjA

This is a truly complex question, I believe. I tried to find solutions, but nothing..

I'm creating a new application. The first section is an image that covers 100% of the browser height.

For this, I am using height: 100vh;

```
<section class="p-hero" id="hero">
</section>

.homepage .p-hero {
    background: url("../img/capa/head-inverse2.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center bottom;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

However, when I move the browser sizes, the page breaks because the image always will cover the browser, but all the items inside this section will stay in the places where which one belong:

It is possible that the height of the section becomes pixels after the page loads? So that it always snaps to the browser size, but will not move if i resize the browser.

Comment: I would help you but I'm finding very hard to understand what is your problem.

Comment: Seems to work fine in windows 7 chrome, might it be a browser compatibility issue? Or I'm misunderstanding the question, do you want that to stay put when you scroll?

Comment: Sorry. I knew it would be difficult to understand, because it's hard to explain haha.. the section height is 100% of the browser size, right?

Go to the site and only decrease the height of the browser size. Then descend a bit. Note that the page break. This is because the image decreases as the browser height decreases. I need the height remains at the size it was loaded.

If I enter the site on a larger computer, the section will show 100%, but if I decrease the height of the browser, nothing happens. That's what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you want it so that when the page first loads, the image will be sized so it fills the full height of the browser. When the user resizes the browser afterwards, you want it to stay this size and not shrink or grow.

If so, this can be done with a simple jQuery function that is only  called when the document is first loaded.

HTML

```
 <img id="hero" src="http://placekitten.com/g/2000/3000">
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hero").css('height',$(window).height());
});
```

Live example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/raVebQ

Comment: Wow Marcelo, i dont believe, just that? hahahhaa.. can you please explain better the code?